# Why my screenshots are darker (then actual image on screen) in Windows 10/11?

Tags: screenshot

Why my screenshots are darker (then actual image on the screen) in Windows 10/11? Screen looks fine, but when I take screenshots they come out with a bit of a darker / greyish shade. I have tried various different Screen-capture options/apps (Snipping-tool & PrnScr button on keyboard) but no difference in results, I even tried going back to couple of Windows "Restore Points" to no avail. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I found the resolution, in my case I had inadvertently installed a screen-contrast / brightness control app that was causing the screen to go darker, it came with a Mouse driver app that had an "Eye comfort control", which I now like very much as it's quick and handy to adjust brightness to comfort eyes.  To avoid capturing the darker screenshots only thing I had to do is to *turn it off* before taking a screenshot (then *turn it back on* once I'm done).

**Example of Darker Screenshot:**

[image]

.

**Example of Correct Screenshot:**

[image]

Hope this helps others.

Comment: If that second shot is supposed to be on a white background, there's still something well out of whack somewhere. That's still literally 50% grey, 129,129,129 instead of 255,255,255. "White" on the first one is a squintingly dark 40,40,40.

Comment: Both screenshots look incredibly dark.  An application shouldn't be able to control the contrast of a screenshot, when you take a screenshot, you are snapping what is being generated within Windows rather than what is being controlled by the display. In other words, I can increase the brightness of my display and it wouldn't affect the screenshot of an application's window with the Snipping-tool which tells me the application in question is doing something extremely strange.

Comment: @Ramhound - that app must be directly adjusting before even the screen profile - adjusting white point. Otherwise the profile & any screenshots, as you say, would not 'see' it at all. I think this would be the perfect opportunity to uninstall that app - making sure it can revert what it has completely messed up in the OP's profiling/calibration.

Comment: Hi I add a comment if someone find this question, on my side when I was using the print screen app of Windows the picture was all the time greyed, like if a shadow or grey layer was applied. In fact it was the HDR in the settings of the screen for my computer, Samsung Galaxy Book 3. Your answer help me to remember I made this change. Thanks

Comment: If you use [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) to vary the colour temperature of the screen, then when using Windows snipping tool to get a screen grab it will change to "normal" colours for the duration of the grab, if that helps.

Comment: Interesting that I also have this problem and I also have an Evoluent VerticalMouse. It's possible that this problem started when I installed those drivers to start using the VerticalMouse again. The difference is that I never enabled the Eye Comfort Control. I should uninstall those drivers and see if that fixes this issue.

Comment: Uninstalling Evoluent drivers did not correct the issue.

Comment: In my case it was one of my monitors that was in HDR mode affecting the snipping tool to make all screenshots darker/flatter, even on a non-HDR screen. Turning of HDR in Windows (System > Screen > HDR) fixed it.